# How to add-to-list to read-in file contents

Tags: list, read

When I do this `(setq v (f-read-text "s.el"))` where `s.el` is of this form

```
((thing1 . thing2) (thing3 . thing4))
```

I get `v` back as one long string. And `(setq v (append (f-read-text "s.el")))` doesn't seem to change things to a list. I want to do a `push` or `add-to-list` an item, but I seem to be adding that item to a list containing a big string. I'd like to return the contents of `s.el` as a list and then do the `push` or `add-to-list`. Then I need to write it back out, again not as a string.

Comment: is `(append (read v) '((thing5 . thing6)))` what you're looking for?

Comment: What is `f-read-text` ?

Comment: Probably from [f.el](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-read-text-path-optional-coding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file contains just one lisp form, all you need to do is

```
(setq v (read (f-read-text "s.el")))
```

(see [Input Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Functions.html)).

If there are several forms, like `(a b) (c d)`, you will need to read in cycle using `read-from-string` or do

```
(read (concat "(" my-string ")"))
```

Comment: After your `(setq v (read (f-read-text "s.el")))` a `(push '(thing5 . thing6) v)` does exactly what I wanted. Thanks.